Stereoisomer and Rotamer?

The correct answer is supposed to be "identical" but I don't know why.
If I go after this flowchart here:

It's clearly a rotamer/conformational (?) I can make them same by rotating around the c-c sigma bond.
Yes, I also notice that they're not 4 different things attached (-H, -R, 2x -CH4) BUT in the following flowchart, there's a butane shown as rotamer, which got 2x -H each as well.

Since "rotamers are stereoisomers produced by rotation (twisting) about sigma bonds" it would be a stereoisomer(?)

In your molecule all the carbons are saturated. In order to have an steric center all the carbon substituents must be the different. In your case, the molecule the molecule has identical substituents ($\ce{R = H}$).

The perspective of the drawing is a bit confusing since you are shown to views of the molecule (above and below the plane of the molecule), and one of the substituents is hidden behind the other.

@PAEP but the butane example in the flowchart also doesn't have 4 different ones, still it's considered a rotamere (thus belongs to stereoisomer)(?)

As PAEP writes the perspective is confusing. If you label the C atoms  1, 2, 3 from the left you can rotate about the 2-3 bond to see that the two structures interconvert and are identical.

@porphyrin yes, I see that but then i don't understand what a rotamer is? The left butane representation could also be interconverted to the right one (3. Image - Newman Projection)

The rotamers in your picture (Isomers) can interconvert so that if you took a snapshot of the structures you would see these two geometries in some proportion (not necessarily 50:50) , but a fraction of a second later any one  molecule could have transformed into the other  rotamer (if you could measure just one at a time to see this) but the ratio of the two types will remain the same on average. (If you drop the temperature a lot you may force just the stable form to be present)

@porphyrin and why do we consider the butane as rotamer and not identical, if we also don't consider the 2-Methylbutan as rotamer (even though it's actually the same situation)?

Maybe I have just a problem with the distinction; till now I thought, that deductively conformers/rotamer --> stereoisomer but not(stereoisomer --> rotamer) because I've read that conformers are special types of (stereo)isomers.

rotamer vs identical, I suppose it depends on whether one can experimentally identify the molecules as being different. They will interconvert as the potential energy has a cosine type nature so a barrier exists between one form and another. It will depend on how big this is vs. thermal energy as to how often this happens.

Conformers are 'technically' stereoisomers, but in real organic chemistry practice most conformers are freely interconverting in standard conditions. Atropoisomers (which I'd advise to look up), i.e. conformers that require some considerable energy to interconvert, and are hence separable and stable, are a notable exception. Weird way to teach stereochemistry... I mean, it is good to be systematic, but a student should certainly not get the idea that those molecules above are practically distinct. You could draw infinite variations of each by rotating the bond by tiny angles.

Hello, David222. Have you talked to your teacher regarding this? I agree with you that they should be classified as conformers/rotamers. There is no sense in emphasizing that they are "identical" (practically speaking), when you are still entertaining the idea of conformers. If you were already discussing more advanced topics, then I could see the sense in emphasizing that at room temperature many of these conformers are "essentially identical" due to relatively free rotation.

In simple molecules such as these you can only have stereoisomers if you have a chiral centre. Here since there's no chiral centre and there's no optical activity its the same compound.


[OP] If I go after this flowchart here

This is not the flowchart you should use because it does not include “identical” as one of the choices.
Here are two other charts that explicitly or implicitly include identical chemical species:

Source: https://shimizu-uofsc.net/orgo/kb/knowledge-base/determine-the-isomeric-relationship-between-two-molecules/

Source: https://labs.chem.ucsb.edu/zakarian/armen/04_01_lecture_02_12_2018.pdf
You can see that there are some contradictions. One chart has "the same" and "stereoisomers" as mutually exclusive (as different branches in the hierarchy), while the other posits that conformational isomers "cannot be separated", which is a functional definition of "identical" (implying that they interconvert faster than the timescale of the separation process). Of course, you can find crystals where the molecules have a certain conformation, and not necessarily the one most common in a liquid or vapor phase, so it is possible to isolate distinct rotamers.
A pragmatic approach to work out the problem the OP presents would be to figure out the name of the two structures. If the name is the same, they are identical. The naming conventions are carefully chosen that identical name implies identical compound, and pairs of non-identical compounds have distinct names. As you learn about more and more subtle reasons for compounds being distinct, you learn about more and more complicated rules for naming.

[OP] It's clearly a rotamer/conformational (?) I can make them same by rotating around the c-c sigma bond.

Yes, the two are rotamers (aka conformational isomers). That does not imply that they are not identical. They have the same name, and it would be hard to obtain either one in pure form. This is different for rotamers that don’t readily interconvert (which have distinct names).

[OP] Since "rotamers are stereoisomers produced by rotation (twisting) about sigma bonds" it would be a stereoisomer(?)

I might not classify different conformations of butane as isomers (as the second chart does), even though they are clearly rotamers/conformational isomers. Isomer sounds like distinct chemical species to me. The Wikipedia article on conformational isomerism states:

When the time scale for interconversion is long enough for isolation of individual rotamers (usually arbitrarily defined as a half-life of interconversion of 1000 seconds or longer), the isomers are termed atropisomers (see: atropisomerism).

It should probably say "Otherwise, the rotamers are considered to be identical chemical species".
The Wikipedia article on isomers links to a chapter of a book by Belostotskii that is critical of using rotations about single bonds to define conformational isomerism because then you rely on what is a single bond and what is not; instead, it suggests using the barrier height of converting from one to another species as the deciding factor (if it is high, you have distinct chemical species, if it is low, you have conformational isomerism).
Below is a custom chart that summarizes the concepts discussed above. It is arranged in a way that the definition of isomer is readily visible (same set of atoms, different spatial arrangement). Also, it includes pairs of structures with identical spatial arrangement (e.g. just drawing a structure twice). You can see that using this hierarchy, identical chemical species appear in two areas. Also, while most of the decisions are made based on the set of atoms and their positions, two decisions require knowledge of chemistry (the ones that mention interconversion).

The bottom line is that “identical” (as a shorthand for same name or identical chemical species) is the best multiple-choice answer, and multiple-choice problems inadequately account for subtleties of complex systems.

I spent some time staring at the Newman projection of these two molecules, trying to decide if they were the same or not (i.e. the same without rotation).  I just confused myself, but I think I decided they were not the same and could only be interconverted by rotation.

On the top I've shown versions with hashed and wedged bonds to hopefully make clear the analogy between these projections and your original images.
On the bottom I've eliminated those hashed and wedged bonds and drawn a mirror plan of symmetry.  I think these molecules are not identical, at least not without free rotation around the bond around which we make the Newman projection.  Interestingly, I think they would be identical if the carbon atom in question were not prochiral: if the "back" carbon atom had no methyl substituent, and we had an isobutane rather than an isopentane, then the two structures would be equivalent.  But, with the methyl substituent, they don't seem to be.
I guess the implication is that at near 0 Kelvin when rotation is hindered, these are not interconverting molecules?
Somehow, I think this is wrong and I suspect there is a plane of symmetry I'm missing somewhere, and that these two structures are equivalent, even without conformational change.  I'll post this answer in an attempt to attract better answers and delete this one when someone who knows better than I do comes along...

They are different rotational conformations of the same molecule (rotamers). The generic formula for the substituted carbon center (methane) can be written AHBB.

That much I agree with @BuckThorn.  The question for me is whether they are actually the same even barring conformational change, such as say at 0 K or some arbitrarily low temperature where rotational/conformational change is hindered.  If they aren't, then it seems like the two conformations are enantiomers of each other, which doesn't make sense because of the AHBB substitution pattern, which because there are two identical substituents, should allow for chirality (BB).  So I'm confused again...

If rigid conformations are compared and rotameric interconversion is not allowed, the mirror images are the same molecule (not enantiomers) if the chosen conformation has a reflection plane that includes the central C, the carbons of the methyl groups "B" and the backbone carbons of the ethyl group "A" (ignoring the orientation of Hs in the methyls), and I believe such a conformation is possible.

You considered only staggered conformations. Eclipsed ones have a plane of symmetry.
